# Update duplicated records MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update, duplicates

I have table like this:

```
q  A B
1  0 1
1  2 0
2  3 0
2  0 4
```

and I want to get something like this:

```
q  A B
1  2 1
1  2 1
2  3 4
2  3 4
```

and then remove duplicated values. Any idea how to do this?
I have duplicated value of q saved in another table if that helps :)

Comment: Can you explain to us the logic behind that?

Comment: You want all q:1 to have A=2 and B=1, and q:2 to have A=3 and B=4?

Comment: What logic? I have duplicated values and I want to agregate this to clean up the mess in database!

Comment: unable to understand the logic behind updating 0's in A and B column to 2 or 3 or 4. Please clearly mention the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *group* your table with a suitable aggregate function (I use `SUM()` below, but you may want to use `MAX()` or something else, depending on your requirements):

```
SELECT   q, SUM(A) A, SUM(B) B
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY q
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/182e1f/1/0).

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE yourtable ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name (q, a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

To update the table try update with self-join:

```
UPDATE Table1 t1
JOIN (
  SELECT q, MAX(A) A, MAX(B) B FROM Table1 GROUP BY q
  ) t2
ON t1.q = t2.q
SET t1.A = t2.A, t1.B = t2.B
```

You can remove duplicates while selecting using `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Table1;
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e731d/2)

Answer (score 0):

ALTER IGNORE TABLE tab_name ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx (q,a,b);

This will drop all the duplicate rows. As an added benefit, future INSERTs that are duplicates will error out.

Answer (score 0):

This is a multi step operation but it gives the exact result you are asking for

```
create table dude (q int, a int, b int);
insert into dude values
(1,  0, 1),
(1,  2, 0),
(2,  3, 0),
(2,  0, 4);

create table dude_temp
select q, max(a), max(b) from dude group by q;

rename table dude      to dude_delete,
             dude_temp to dude;

drop table dude_delete;
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6338/1)